# Enum.TryParse doesn't accept my out parameter as an object

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, generics

I have the following line:

`var parseSortField = (BasicProfileSortableFields?)Enum.TryParse(typeof(BasicProfileSortableFields?), sortOptions.SortColumn, out BasicProfileSortableFields? sortField);`

Around the out parameter, I'm getting an error that says

> Argument 3: cannot convert from 'out Services.Models.BasicProfileSortableFields?' to 'out object?'

Regular parsing works but I'm trying to catch a scenario where my string is not in the mentioned enum. Also the enum I'm referencing is from a nuget package and not actually written by me if that helps.

Comment: `BasicProfileSortableFields?` what ist that `?` here?

Comment: @fubo the parameter is expecting a nullable object so I made the enum nullable

Comment: when you add ?, it becomes Nullable type rather than `object`, also, you cannot typecast the return value of TryParse which is bool.  you need to check return value and then typecast the 3rd `out` param variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

nullable enums can's be handled by `Enum.TryParse`

workaround: handle the null case with a `?:` ternary conditional operator

```
BasicProfileSortableFields temp;
BasicProfileSortableFields? parseSortField = Enum.TryParse<BasicProfileSortableFields>(sortOptions.SortColumn, out temp) ? (BasicProfileSortableFields?)temp : null);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of [`Enum.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-6.0) method:

- Non-generic ones with a `Type` parameter first and an `out object` parameter at the end
- Generic ones without the `Type` parameter (because the generic type parameter is used instead) and with an `out TEnum` parameter at the end

Currently it looks like you're half-way between the two - but with a nullable final parameter (`out TEnum?` instead of `out TEnum`). Additionally, you're trying to cast the result of the `TryParse` method to the enum type - whereas actually it returns a `bool` saying whether or not the parsing succeeded.

I would advise using the generic forms, in code a little like Fubo's answer, but declaring the `temp` variable "inline" in the call:

```cs
var sortField =
    Enum.TryParse<BasicProfileSortableFields>(sortOptions.SortColumn, out var temp)
        ? temp
        : default(BasicProfileSortableFields?);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Enum.TryParse` returns a boolean, and the 3rd parameter is `out object?`. You may want to use [`Enum.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-6.0#system-enum-parse(system-type-system-string)) instead? In which case, just eliminate the third parameter, and wrap the call in a try..catch if you care to handle when the parse fails.

Also, I think you want the first parameter to be the type of your enum, not the type of a Nullable wrapper for your enum, but I could be mistaken on that.

Alternatively, to keep using [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-6.0#system-enum-tryparse(system-type-system-string-system-object@)), you should first check the result to see if the parse failed, and get the out parameter as an `object?`, which you can then cast to your target type if the parse succeeded, like this:

```
BasicProfileSortableFields parseSortField;

if(Enum.TryParse(typeof(BasicProfileSortableFields), sortOptions.SortColumn, out object? sortField))
{
    parseSortField = (BasicProfileSortableFields)sortField.Value;
}
else
{
    // Handle failed parse condition here
}
```

Comment: Whoops - I'd looked at the wrong piece of code (another answer instead of the original code). Rather than advising the continued use of the non-generic overloads, it makes more sense to use the generic ones.